# Function modifies list

Tags: python, list, function, reference

```
def make_Ab(A,b):
    n = len(A)
    Ab = list(A)
    for index in range(0,n):
        Ab[index].append(b[index][0])
    print(A)
    return Ab.copy()

A = [[0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0], [1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 5.0], [2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 4.0]]

b = [[1],[2],[3]]

print(A)
```

`[[0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0], [1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 5.0], [2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 4.0]]`

```
Ab = make_Ab(A,b)
print(A)
```

`[[0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1], [1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 5.0, 2], [2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 3]]`

I don't get why does my function modify my original list. I didn't specify`A` as global in function (I've even tried to declare it in a different function so it won't be global), I didn't pass it through reference (like `Ab = A`). What's the problem?

Comment: `list(A)` and `Ab.copy()` are shallow copies. The sublists aren't copied.

Comment: `from copy import deepcopy`

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but I think it's probably too verbose as-is. Which part of it helped you out? Can I trim or eliminate the other parts?

Comment: I don't think its too verbose, it's good as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that, while you're not modifying the *variable* (which you can't do without `global`), you *are* modifying the *value*.

This can be a bit confusing at first. These two look like they do the same thing:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a = a + [1]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 1]
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a.append(1)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 1]
```

But they're not. The first one is making a new list out of `a` and `[1]` and then binding that new list back to the name `a`. If there was some other reference to that same list, it would be unchanged. The second one, on the other hand, is changing the actual list object that `a` names. If there was some other reference to that same list, it would change.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> a = a + [1]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> a.append(1)
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 1]
```

What you're doing in your code is the second one, changing the value of the list object. Which means that every reference to that list object, even a name you don't have access to, will see the change.

But you're not modifying `A` itself, you're modifying `list(A)`. Shouldn't that be a new copy of the list?

Yes, it is—but, even if `Ab` is a different list from `A`, `Ab[0]` is still the same list as `A[0]`. You've made a new list that references the same sublists as the original one. So when you mutate those sublists… same problem.

If you want to change this, you can do one of two things:

- Copy all of the sublists, as well as the list, at the top of the function, so you mutate the copy instead of the original.
- Don't use any mutating operations on the lists; build a new one.

The first one is a simple change: instead of `Ab = list(A)`, do `Ab = copy.deepcopy(A)` or `Ab = [list(sub) for sub in Ab]`.

The second one requires rewriting your code a bit:

```
def make_Ab(A,b):
    n = len(A)
    Ab = []        
    for index in range(0,n):
        Ab.append(A[n] + [b[index][0]])
    return Ab
```

(Or, of course, you can rewrite that as a list comprehension.)

Comment: Thanks a lot!. One small question, If I return a list from a function, should I return a deep copy?

Comment: @GeorgePalasanu Usually not. Normally, when you create a new object and return it, the only references to that object are your function's locals (which are about to go away) and your caller, so there's no sharing to worry about. The only exception would be if you stored it somewhere permanent (like an object attribute), and wanted to make sure the caller had a completely independent copy. Which usually doesn't come up.

Answer (score 0):

## Passing Arguments to Function - Python

> Python uses a mechanism, which is known as "Call-by-Object", sometimes
>   also called "Call by Object Reference" or "Call by Sharing".

### Call by Value - Immutable Arguments

If we pass immutable arguments like integers, strings or tuples to a function, the passing acts like call-by-value.

### Call by Object or Call by Object Reference - Mutable Arguments

If we pass mutable arguments like lists and dictionaries to a function, they are passed by object reference.

## Solution

The solution to your problem is to use ***deepcopy***.

1. Add ***from copy import deepcopy***
2. Replace ***Ab = list(A)*** with ***Ab = deepcopy(A)***
3. Replace ***return Ab.copy()*** with ***return Ab***

### main.py

```
from copy import deepcopy


def make_Ab(A, b):
    n = len(A)
    Ab = deepcopy(A)
    print("\nmake_Ab-before append: \n    A=", A)
    for index in range(0, n):
        Ab[index].append(b[index][0])
    print("\nmake_Ab-after append: \n    A=", A)
    return Ab

A = [[0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0], [1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 5.0], [2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 4.0]]

b = [[1], [2], [3]]

print("Before: make_Ab call, \n    A=", A)

Ab = make_Ab(A, b)

print("\nAfter: make_Ab call, \n    A=", A)
print("\nAfter: make_Ab call, \n    Ab=", Ab)
```

## Output

[image]